# Plesk alternative for windows

Tags: windows-server-2003, plesk

I'm searching for a free alternative to Plesk for my windows server 2003. Anybody knows an alternative.

Comment: This is server administration software - not a programming question.

Comment: Plenty of similar questions get left open. A programmer may well need something like Plesk to admin his/her box.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there aren't any. Plesk bought Helm it's only major competitor in the Windows space. The only "ok" free panel I know is ISPConfig but it's only for Linux.

Our company is also searching for an alternative to Plesk, for Windows hosting.

Edit 25 Oct 2010: DotNetPanel renamed to WebsitePanel appears to be open source:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/websitepanel/

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this is not helpful but why do you wish to have a control panel for Windows? at best its a GUI on a GUI, you can't touch IIS as it will break the panel etc etc.

To be honest I would stick to a non control panel windows server, its much easier to administrate in my honest opinion.

Comment: Perhaps, this should have been a comment once you gain enough reputation?